# CIAffineClamp filter does not clamp

Tags: ios, swift, crop, cifilter, ciimage

I am trying to do simple thing. 
I have image view with image in it. I want to translate image by half width of image size and clamp the pixels at the edge of the transformed image, extending them outwards with help of `CIAffineClamp`. But it's no working. It's do nothing. I have attached sample project.

My code is:

```
func translateAndClamp(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return image
        }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width / 2, y: 0)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
        filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform), forKey: "inputTransform")

        let context = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: true])

        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else {
            return image
        }

        let extent = ciImage.extent.applying(transform)

        guard let result = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: extent) else {
            return image
        }

        return UIImage(cgImage: result, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    }
```

[Sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O1mr50lze_NLT2pYz0f6etINs379115I)

**Updates**

```
    private func makeResultImageCroppedAndRotated(from image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let angle = CGFloat(gestureHandler.rotation(from: imgView.transform))

        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return image
        }

        let rotatedCGImage = rotateImage(image: cgImage, angle: angle)
        let rotated = UIImage(cgImage: rotatedCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        let cropArea = makeCropArea(for: rotated, in: imgView, anchor: layoutContentView)
        let cropped = cropImage(image: rotatedCGImage, to: cropArea)

        return UIImage(cgImage: cropped, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    }


    private func makeCropArea(for image: UIImage, in imageView: UIImageView, anchor: UIView) -> CGRect {
        let boundingRect = LayoutCorrectionUtility.boundingAspectRect(for: image, inside: imageView)
        let factor = LayoutCorrectionUtility.factor(for: image, insideBoundingRect: boundingRect)

        let x = (anchor.bounds.origin.x - boundingRect.origin.x) * factor
        let y = (anchor.bounds.origin.y - boundingRect.origin.y) * factor
        let width = anchor.frame.width * factor
        let height = anchor.frame.height * factor

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }


    func rotateImage(image: CGImage, angle: CGFloat) -> CGImage {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: image)

        let newAngle = angle * CGFloat(-1)

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(newAngle), 0, 0, 1)
        let affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(transform)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
        filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(NSValue(cgAffineTransform: affineTransform), forKey: "inputTransform")

        let contex = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: true])

        guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else {
            return image
        }

        let extent = ciImage.extent.applying(affineTransform)
        guard let result = contex.createCGImage(outputImage, from: extent) else {
            return image
        }

        return result
    }


    func cropImage(image: CGImage, to rect: CGRect) -> CGImage {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: image).clampedToExtent()

        var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -CGFloat(image.height))

        let contex = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: true])

        guard let result = contex.createCGImage(ciImage, from: rect.applying(transform)) else {
            return image
        }

        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you also applied the transform to the output `extent`. Here is the code that works for me with some comments:

```
func translateAndClamp(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    // no need to use use the internal CGImage
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
        return image
    }

    // Important: use the CIImage's width here since the UIImage's size
    // is in points, not pixels.
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: ciImage.extent.width / 2, y: 0)

    // This does the same as CIAffineClamp, but is shorter and doesn't return an Optional.
    let outputImage = ciImage.transformed(by: transform).clampedToExtent()

    // I would advise against using the software renderer, but maybe you have your reasons.
    // Also, if you want to call this method more then once, it's better to create the
    // context on object initialization and re-use it every time since it's expensive to create.
    let context = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: true])

    // Important: don't apply the transform to the output extent!
    // Think of this as the "window" on the image you want to draw.
    // Since you moved the image "inside" the window with the transform,
    // the window needs to be the original image's extent.
    let extent = ciImage.extent

    guard let result = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: extent) else {
        return image
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: result, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
}
```

Comment: Hello, Frank. Can you please help me out with three operations: rotation, scale, translation and crop.

For rotation i am using `CGAffineTransform + clampedToExtent`

Comment: First I am rotate image.
Next I am trying to calculate crop area based on transform parameters: scale, translate.
Next I am crop rotated image. But it s working not good enough

Comment: Actually I think that my crop area is correct, I think my problem in crop operation itself. I need to crop and clamp transparent pixels of new image

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can post some example/mockup of what the result should look like?

Comment: Photo: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/12/d9a64a07306d06a0ef083b256fd93f65-full.jpg

This image is result of rotating (CGAffineClamp) and translating and cropping. As you can see: there is clamped pixels (after rotating) and black area.I want to black area will be clamped also to. How to achieve that?

Comment: Could you please add this to your example project? I would need to see the order in which you apply the operations.

Comment: I have updated question. Added all functions which I use. I want to remind you, perhaps the `cropArea` is not quite correctly calculated, but the main question is not this, but that there are black pixels on result image.

Comment: Could you please add that to your sample project? It's really hard to debug just by looking at the code.

Comment: Schelgel Hello. Thanks to you I figured out how to clamp rotated image.https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/15/62d783e21475d0f7ae5ffe80821570d0-full.jpg

As you can see CoreImage does not clamp corner, only sides

Comment: Here is the thing, when I do `ciImage.clampedToExtent().transformed(by: rotation)` CoreImage rotates, clamping pixels, but also right and bottom lines of the image CoreImage makes as black pixels.

And next when I am trying to do crop of image, these black pixels clamped into BLACK area

Comment: Yes, clamp will only repeat the value of the closest pixel, and for corners, there's only one pixel that is closest (the corner pixel). As for the black area: I guess the problem lies in the `rect` you are passing to `contex.createCGImage`. This needs to be the extent of the final result you want to get, so nothing you should apply any rotations to.

Comment: I am passing right crop area extent, but also I am need to applying some transform: `(scaleX: 1, y: -1)`  and `.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -CGFloat(ciImage.extent.height))` because of inverted coordinate systems, so: `guard let final = context.createCGImage(rotated, from:cropArea.applying(invertionTransform)) else {`

Comment: As the result I get correct crop, but black pixels sometimes

Comment: I'm sorry Gikas, but without an example project I can't figure out what's going on...

Comment: 8(( It's so much need to extract from project to make sample project with reproduced problem